# Mistake in plotting stocks

Tags: python, plot, finance, stock

As I cannot find the mistake, I post it here. The task is relatively simple and from a python beginner program:

1. Use pd.read_csv() to import 'stock_prices.csv', parsing the 'Date' column and also setting the 'Date' column as index before assigning the result to stock_prices. Inspect the result using .info().
2. Calculate the price return for the index components by dividing the last row of stock_prices by the first, subtracting 1 and multiplying by 100. Assign the result to price_return.
   Plot a horizontal bar chart of the sorted returns with the title Stock Price Returns.

Here is my solution (wrong):

```
# Import prices and inspect result
stock_prices = pd.read_csv('stock_prices.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')
print(stock_prices.info())

# Calculate the returns
price_return = stock_prices.iloc[-1].div(stock_prices.iloc[0]).sub(1).mul(100)
price_return.sort_values(inplace=True)

# Plot horizontal bar chart of sorted price_return   
price_return.plot.barh(title='Stock Price Returns')
plt.show()
```

And there ist a hint:

Have you calculated price_return according to the instructions? Use stock_prices.iloc[-1] and stock_prices.iloc[0] to access the last and then 1st rows of stock_prices. The arithmetic should be completed using .div(), .sub(), and .mul().

Can you help me with that task?

Try to followed the task and the hint

Comment: we cannot see any data. Please post the input data, the results you are getting and the results you would expect, so we can see where is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

#### Print tickers

```
print(tickers)
```

#### Import prices and inspect result

```
stock_prices = pd.read_csv('stock_prices.csv',parse_dates=['Date'],index_col='Date')
print(stock_prices.info())
```

#### Calculate the returns

```
price_return = stock_prices.iloc[-1].div(stock_prices.iloc[0]).sub(1).mul(100)  

price_return.sort_values().plot(kind='barh',title='Stock Price Returns')
plt.show()
```